# 'GetRows()' type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I have declared array:

```
 Dim VArr(3) as Integer
```

and I got the type mismatch error in:

```
VArr(0) = rs.GetRows(1, 0).
```

and my select is "select name from table1".

Comment: this select returns 15 recordsets

Comment: post your code, sample of data input, expected data output, actual data output

Comment: is name an Integer?  Perhaps you're trying to add a string when it's expecting an int.  If you have just Dim VArr(3)  {leave off the 'as Integer' part} does it work?

Comment: Maybe `VArr(0) = rs.GetRows()(1, 0)`  You should compare the expected parameters for GetRows to what you have in your code - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx  Also, the first dimension in the resulting array is the Field, and the second is the record number, so maybe (0, 1) is what you want.